# Should i wrap mysqli prepared statement in a if

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Should i wrap mysqli prepared statement in a if statement like

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    ...
}
```

Instead of

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)
```

If i use custom error handling

Comment: What do you mean by "I use custom error handling"? What custom error handling do you have in place?

Comment: I just think if I have a custom error handler will none error message be shown. Just a normal set_error_handler to handle and not display errors